# Filter datetime column in MS SQL 2008 server with a parsed string value

Tags: c#, sql-server, date

I'm not sure how I can make the title of this question more specific.

I am working on an ASP.NET MVC3 application. There I use jQuery grid to show data from the database and have few filters. One of them should allow the user to search by date.

In my database the `Date` column looks like this :

[image: Date Column]

I pass the selected date to the back end where I parse the date string like this :

```
 else if (property.PropertyType == typeof(DateTime))
                        {
                            DateTime value;
                            if (DateTime.TryParse(rule.Data, out value))
                            {
                                selector = ExpressionEquals<T>(rule.Field, value);
                            }
                        }
```

Where the variable `value` looks like this : `03/06/2013 12:24:30`.

The problem is that in my database the `Date` column has a different format at least from what I can see in the Management Studio, and along with that in fact I don't want to filter so specifically (The time is only for user information, but in fact I need only the date).

I need make the data from the jQuery grid usable for the kind of search I want. In fact the date string that comes from the grid looks exactly like the parsed value. In other words the `rule.Data` value is `"03/06/2013 12:24:30"`.

How can use this data to filter data only by date but keeping the table column type of `datetime`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Filter by range between "03/06/2013 00:00:00.000" and "03/06/2013 23:59:59.999"

Answer (score 1):

Hey Leron use date format like this  "03/06/2013 00:00:00" and "03/06/2013 23:59:59" may be it will help

Comment: Well, all this is inherited stuff. Even the search method is not written by me I try to fit in. Maybe I'll try Orsols answer if there is nothing better.

Answer (score 1):

you can use convert function sql sever e.g

SELECT field1, field2, field3, datetimefield 
FROM table1 
WHERE Convert(date, datetimefield) = Convert(date, @datetimeparamter)