# Parsing out Date from Datetime type in SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-server-2012

As I am new to SQL Server, I have been trying to implement following thing:

**What I have**

I have a `Sale` table as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Sale](
[SaleID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[ModelID] [int] NOT NULL,
[CustomerID] [int] NOT NULL,
[SaleTimeStamp] [datetime] NULL,
[IsPresent] [bit] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

where entries in `SaleTimeStamp` are as follows: `2013-06-04 12:14:32.260`

**What I want:**

I need to create a table having following attributes:

```
Date
Month
Year
Quarter
```

Where all of the columns I have to derive from `SaleTimeStamp` of the `Sale` table, and quarter is based on the value of `Month` (first/second/thrird...). I want to create a stored procedure for this functionality. I have gone through [Filter datetime column in MS SQL 2008 server with a parsed string value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17144934/filter-datetime-column-in-ms-sql-2008-server-with-a-parsed-string-value). But still not able to figure out. I don't know how to proceed.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!!

Answer (score 3):

To get the date you can just cast the value to the `DATE` data type:

```
SELECT SaleTimeStamp,CAST(SaleTimeStamp AS DATE) [Date] FROM dbo.Sale;
```

To get the date parts, you can use the `DATEPART` function. ([See DATEPART on msdn.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174420.aspx))

```
SELECT SaleTimeStamp,
DATEPART(MONTH, SaleTimeStamp) AS [Month], 
DATEPART(QUARTER, SaleTimeStamp) AS [Quarter], 
DATEPART(YEAR, SaleTimeStamp) AS [Year] 
FROM dbo.Sale;
```

Comment: You should consider accepting the answer if this has helped you.